# asp dotnet core on linux: missing all bower packages

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, bower, .net-core

For simplicity I am focusing one just one bower-installed library, but it doesn't load any bower-installed package under /lib

Project works fine under Windows, but it doesn't find bower-installed backages under Linux.

Chrome shows this error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/lib/pikaday/pikaday.js 

404 not found
```

In the view:

```
<script src="/lib/pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
```

I have my `bower.json` in the solution:

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "handsontable": "0.24.3"
  }
}
```

(`pickaday.js` is part of the `handsontable` package)

How can I make `dotnet run` / `dotnet build` / `dotnet publish` on linux include those bower packages?

Comment: did you run `bower install` so it retrieves the dependencies?

Comment: @Baklap4 That was it, thank you so much. I knew it had to be something very basic but I was unable to find the info. I'll write an answer with another gotcha I've found during the process, in case anybody else is interested in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As user Baklap4 mentioned in the comments, it needs to run `bower install` so it retrieves the dependencies via npm (it's not done automatically as in Visual Studio).

Of course you need Bower installed first (otherwise on `dotnet publish` you will get the error "'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command"):

```
npm install -g bower
```

Running that in Ubuntu, I encountered this other problem:

```
bower install
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

The solution can be found [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3911), which is adding a logical link in linux:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Finally, repeat:

```
bower install
```