# The dependency MySql.Data >= 7.0.6-ir31 could not be resolved

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core

I tried to deploy my asp.net core web api to nginx, the web api project reference a class library. The class library installed MySql.Data package from nuget. After copied the whole project to ubuntu and executed "dotnet restore" command, all works well in this step. But when I execute 'dotnet publish' command, I got an error:

Compiling App.DAL.Core for .NETStandard, Version=v1.6 /home/.../project.json: error NU1001: The dependency MySql.Data >= 7.0.6-ir31 could not be resolved

I have check this thread,

[MySQL -> .NET Core Dependency error (MySql.Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303685/mysql-net-core-dependency-error-mysql-data)

Changed IR to ir, but still not work. Please see my project.json files

DAL.Core Porject.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "MySql.Data": "7.0.6-ir31",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Web API Project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "log4net": "2.0.7",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "App.DAL.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "MySql.Data": "7.0.6-ir31",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0",
    "System.Text.Encoding": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0",
    "System.Net.Requests": "4.0.11",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you change it in both places? You have the reference in your class library and in your application

Comment: Sure, the two project.json files are changed

Comment: Also, I can see both of the project.lock.json files have been changed from IR31 to ir31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code below to DAL.Core project's project.json file solves the issue

```js
"runtimes": {
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
  }
```